# Robot framework how to verify value of element in window

Tags: selenium, robotframework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS0yw.png)

I want to validate the value 'Ping Information For' that it exists in the window.

Comment: It looks like the first think you need to do is work through a robot framework tutorial. Then, when you try to solve the problem and get stuck, come back here and ask a specific question. Be sure to show us what you've tried and what research you've done to try and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own keyword where you can check whether text at given locator is equal with expected string value

```
To Verify Text
  [Arguments]      ${locator}    ${expectedString}
  ${Somevariable}=    Get Text     ${locator}
  Should Be Equal       ${Somevariable}      ${expectedString}
```

here `Should Be Equal` is from `built in` library and `Get Text` is from selenium2library.

Reference Links: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Equal
http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Text